# Как заполнить поля таблицы и внести id записи в поле другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток! есть такая задача: заполнить поля одной таблицы и внести id этой записи в поле другой таблицы. Можно ли сделать это одним запросом?

Comment: Можно с помощью UPDATE и точечную нотацию.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Читайте про сложные mysql запросы. Пример:

- [Сложный MySQL запрос — CASE, COUNT и SUM](http://qane.ru/2012/01/26/1/)
- [Двойной запрос mysql](http://javascript.ru/forum/server/34155-dvojjnojj-zapros-mysql.html)